# can a WCF service consume it's own service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I was wondering if this is possible: I want to create a set of servers that communicate with each other. The servers would be similar to each other (not a master - slave scenario). Is it possible to do this using WCF? 
If this is possible, I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction. (a good example or the right keywords to search for in google)

Thanks,

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to deploy multiple instances of the same service onto different servers that communicate with each other?

Comment: @Jens H - yes. That is exactly my goal. The servers will communicate with each other based on a set of configuration rules and requests from the client.

Comment: @OSH Is it the same service? What is your use case?

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin It would be the same service. The use case is multiple servers controlling the flow of data across the entire network of servers. When a new data arrives to a server it will notify all the subscribed peers about it, and accept queries by them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can. Just get the WSDL and then generate the class. It does not detect that it is "the same service".

Beware of infinite recursion though. I.E. a method calling itself, thus creating a loop and never terminating it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this a possible scenario.

However, instead of calling the service API directly I suggest to consider sending messages between the services, like the Microsoft Message Queue (MSMQ).

This decouples the several service instances from each other and reduces the need for dependencies of Service Reference (for example). The services would not need to know much of each other.

As soon as a message arrives, it is handled by a designated handler method. As you always work with different service instances this way, you would not need to bother with any recursive calls that Oskar mentioned.

WCF can easiliy be configured to use MSMQ as the underlying transport medium and **supports it out-of-the-box.**

Some articles/ tutorials to get you started:

- MSDN: [MSMQ and WCF: Getting Started](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/motleyqueue/archive/2009/05/31/msmq-and-wcf-getting-started.aspx)
- [Message Queuing to Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751490)
- A more compley scenario with secured communation: [Creating a WCF Service with MSMQ Communication and Certificate
  Security](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/326909/Creating-a-WCF-Service-with-MSMQ-Communication-and) (Code Project)
- [Leveraging MSMQ in ASP.NET Applications](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/internet/article.php/c19563/Leveraging-MSMQ-in-ASPNET-Applications.htm)

Comment: Thanks. For now I'm going to give "pure" WCF a try (I am ashamed to say that I am doing that since it seems simpler and less requirements on the server, and simpler for me to work with). I did some reading and the MSMQ seems like it would not help me a lot (I am not afraid of losing messages).